# Finding Pairs Using r

Tags: r

The goal: Find out how often two people appear together within a group of cases.

My original data contained a court case number followed by fields that contained identifiers for people involved in each case. There could be up to 15 people in each case.

It looks like this:

```
case_formatted person1 person2 person3 person4 .... 
1234            A         B       C       D
2345            B         E       F
3456            F         B       G 
4567            A
5678            D         F
```

I used a melt function to make the data more vertical. It now looks like this:

```
case_formatted     person_variable     person_value
1234                   Person 1              A
2345                   Person 1              B    
3456                   Person 1              F        
4567                   Person 1              A
5678                   Person 1              D
```

and so on through a possible Person15, with the case numbers (case_formatted) appearing each time there's an additional person to list.

How do I now find out how often each person appears within the same case together? Ultimately, I want a frequency for each possible pairing. In this example, how many cases do Person B and Person F appear in together? There are about 2,000 cases total.

Comment: That means there will be `combn(1:15,2)` or `105` combinations? Are you sure this is what you want?

Comment: One way to do it is through networks: create a network of 15 nodes, and each time two persons appear together, you increase the tie strength by 1.  Maybe easier (and conceptually the same) is to do it with sets: each case is a set of up to 15 individuals, and then you simply walk through the sets and increase the corresponding frequency.  Use loops, it does not seem to be that large data.

Comment: Is it important for you to know whether "A" is Person 1 or Person 2, or Person 15 etc. ?

Comment: No, @col. slade, the position of the person in the sequence doesn't matter.

Comment: @jensmith see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come up with the following approach:

```
#Your sample data
df <- data.frame(case_formatted = c(1234, 2345, 3456, 4567, 5678), 
                 person1 = c("A","B","F","A","D"), 
                 person2 = c("B","E","B", NA,"F"), 
                 person3 = c("C","F","G", NA, NA), 
                 person4 = c("D", NA, NA, NA, NA),
                 stringsAsFactors =  F)

#Names of all persons
persons <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G")

#Case IDs
cases <- df$case_formatted

#Transpose to Matrix
df.t <- as.data.frame(t(df[2:ncol(df)]))

#Make logical matrix
d <- as.data.frame(t(sapply(df.t, function(x) persons %in% x)))
colnames(d) <- persons
e <- cbind(Case.ID = cases, d)

#Output
e
   Case.ID     A     B     C     D     E     F     G
V1    1234  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
V2    2345 FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
V3    3456 FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
V4    4567  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
V5    5678 FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

This data frame now lists all case ID's and who out of all possible people in persons appeared in them.

One possibility is to use the Hadley Wickham's package 'dplyr' to easily work with the data. It has a very intuitive interface to work with data e.g.

```
library(dplyr)
e %>% filter(A == TRUE & B == TRUE)
```

will show you all the rows (court cases) for which A was in court and B was in court.

```
  Case.ID    A    B    C    D     E     F     G
1    1234 TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

So for the sample data, it happened once. If you use the same type of query all the time, you can also write a function, e.g.

```
howMany <- function(first, second, data = e) {
  together <- data %>% filter_(paste0(first,' == T',' & ',second, ' == T'))
  output <- paste(first, 'and', second, 'appeared', length(together[,1]), 'x together in court.')
  cat(output)
}
```

So then you could use:

```
howMany('A','C')

A and C appeared 1 x together in court.
```